# Determine entity or table name inside EF Command Interceptor

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Three is a `IDbCommandTreeInterceptor` interceptor attached to EF via the `DbConfiguration` in a project I'm working with.

The `IDbCommandTreeInterceptor` has a method `TreeCreated` which has a main parameter of `DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext` - it provides this. Is there anyway to get the underlying entity or table on which the command is operating? mabye from the context?

Comment: It may not be a single table. See [here](http://marisks.net/2016/02/27/entity-framework-soft-delete-and-automatic-created-modified-dates/).

Comment: @ivan-stoev supposing its an insert or update command, do these operate on these single tables or more?

Comment: They have separate classes - `DbDeleteCommandTree`, `DbInsertCommandTree` and `DbUpdateCommandTree`. They all inherit from `DbModificationCommandTree` which has property `Target`, so according to the link, you can use `var table = (EntityType) modificationCommand.Target.VariableType.EdmType;`